# How to apply different color to RegionPlot3D surfaces?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d

```
RegionPlot3D[
x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 0.75}, {y, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1}, 
ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}]
```

I got output as below:
  [image]

How to apply different color to each surface as below? 
[image]

Comment: That's not that easy: The polygons of the indicated surfaces are stored in a common `GraphicsGroup` within within the generated `Graphics3D` object. At least to me, it is not clear how to seperate these polygons in order to assign different `Directives` to them...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
mesh = {Range[-1, .75, 1.75/15], Range[-1, .75, 1.75/15], Range[-1, 1, 2/15]};
pp3d = ParametricPlot3D[{{x, .75, z}, {.75, x, z}}, {x, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  RegionFunction -> (#^2 + #2^2 + #3^2 <= 1 &), PlotStyle -> {Glow @ Red, Glow @ Blue},
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> mesh];
cp3d = ContourPlot3D[x^2 + (y)^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, -1, 0.75}, {y, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
  MeshFunctions -> {# &, #2 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> mesh,
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}]
Show[cp3d, pp3d]
```

[image]

**Update:** an alternative way to post-process `RegionPlot3D` output:

```
rp3d = RegionPlot3D[x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 0.75}, {y, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, 
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}]; 

Normal[rp3d] /. {p : Polygon[{{a_, _, _} ..}, ___] :> {Glow @ Blue, p},
  p : Polygon[{{_, b_, _} ..}, ___] :> {Glow @ Red, p}}
```

[image]

**Update 2:** if you don't mind blending of colors you can also use `Lighting` option settings

```
lighting = {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]},
  {"Spot", Blue, {1.5, 0, 0}, Pi/2}, {"Spot", Red, {0, -.75, 0}, Pi}}; 
RegionPlot3D[x^2 + (y)^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 0.75}, {y, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1}, 
 ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> True, Axes -> True, Lighting -> lighting]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Replace the polygons of the clipped surface according to their x or y coordinates. The tricky business is that the polygons of the two clipped faces are mixed together in two groups, as @Henrik observed, so I reconstructed an equivalent polygon for each face using [`ConvexHullMesh`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexHullMesh.html).  This necessitates projecting the points on each face to 2D and then lifting the convex hull back up to 3D.

```
plot = RegionPlot3D[
  x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= 1, {x, -1, 0.75}, {y, -1, 0.75}, {z, -1, 1}, 
  ImageSize -> 400, Boxed -> True, 
  Axes -> True,(*Lighting->{{"Ambient", White}},*)
  Lighting -> {{"Directional", Gray, ImageScaled[{2, 0, 2}]}}, 
  AxesLabel -> Automatic]

With[{coords = Cases[plot, GraphicsComplex[c_, __] :> c, Infinity]},
 plot /. p_Polygon /; 
    coords[[1, p[[1, 2, 2]], 1]] == 0.75 || 
     coords[[1, p[[1, 2, 2]], 2]] == 0.75 :>
   {Red, Cases[
     Cases[plot, {_, 0.75, _}, Infinity][[All, {3, 1}]] // 
        ConvexHullMesh // Show // Normal, 
     Polygon[ch_] :> 
      Polygon[RotateLeft[PadRight[ch, {Automatic, 3}, 0.75], {0, 1}]],
      Infinity],
    Blue, 
    Cases[Cases[plot, {0.75, _, _}, Infinity][[All, {2, 3}]] // 
        ConvexHullMesh // Show // Normal, 
     Polygon[ch_] :> Polygon[PadLeft[ch, {Automatic, 3}, 0.75]], 
     Infinity]}
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The odd lighting makes the blue color almost black, except at certain angles.  This is as easy as it is because the desired surfaces are exactly on the plot boundaries (and because the faces are convex).